# Partial active pattern

Tags: f#, functional-programming, f#-interactive

I have to write a function for school which determines from a poker hand if it has two pairs. I should do it with partial active pattern, but I am stuck here.

```
let (|TwoPairs|_|) (x: (string * string) list) =
    x
    |> List.groupBy snd
    |> List.sortByDescending fst
    |> List.filter (fun (_, v) -> v |> List.length = 2)
    |> List.length = 2

let x2 =
    match [("S", "2"); ("S", "6"); ("S", "6"); ("S", "4"); ("S", "2")] with
    | TwoPairs p -> sprintf "Two pairs"
    | _ -> "Nothing"
```

How do I give back the last comparison as an option and what should be in Some _ in this case?

Comment: I just want to mention that *this* is what all "Please help me with my homework" questions should look like. It states up-front that it's for a homework assignment, so we know how much help is appropriate, and the question is "here's what I've done so far, but I'm stuck on the next step". Well done. +1 for the question, and I wish I could give it a +5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the last line of your active pattern function is quite confusing because of the indentation and the implicit grouping due to operator precedence. I would write it like this to return an option:

```
let (|TwoPairs|_|) (x: (string * string) list) =
    x
    |> List.groupBy snd
    |> List.sortByDescending fst
    |> List.filter (fun (_, v) -> v |> List.length = 2)
    |> List.length
    |> function 2 -> Some () | _ -> None
```

When you return `Option<unit>`, then you don't have to bind to `p`, because it would be unit and represents the absence of a value. So you would use the pattern like this:

```
let x2 =
    match [("S", "2"); ("S", "6"); ("S", "6"); ("S", "4"); ("S", "2")] with
    | TwoPairs -> sprintf "Two pairs"
    | _ -> "Nothing"
```

I'm not sure if there's any benefit to using an active pattern here. It would be simpler to have a plain function that returns bool and use it like this:

```
if twoPairs [("S", "2"); ("S", "6"); ("S", "6"); ("S", "4"); ("S", "2")]
then sprintf "Two pairs"
else "Nothing"
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using active pattern, because it was a requirement.